# Tikzexternalize and `underset`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

Using `\tikzexternalize`, I have discovered that wrapping a `tikzpicture` in `\underset` causes tikzexteranlize to compile the picture three times; e.g., observe the output of

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
        \[
            \underset{a}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \]
\end{document}
```

I guess this is also why compiling a document that contains many such constructions (without tikzexternalize) takes relatively long.
I have observed that replacing `\underset` by

```
\newsavebox\undersetbox
\newcommand{\boxedunderset}[2]{
    \savebox\undersetbox{#2}
    \underset{#1}{\usebox \undersetbox}
}
```

solves the problem. What's the issue, which commands are affected, and is there an easy fix the issue more generally?

Comment: Inside `\underset` the TikZ diagram will be forwarded to `\binrel@` which typesets it twice (into a box) to measure something and then it will used a third type when it is actually put on the page. The `external` library doesn't detect that it's the same picture again and does it thing three times as well. An easy fix would be to name your picture via `\tikzsetnextfilename` or `/tikz/external/figure name`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, that would solve the problem. But also when I don't use externalize, the behaviour of `\underset` increases the compilation time noticeably I guess.

Comment: Well, if you notice the compilation time then something along the lines `\boxedunderset` might just be the right solution. If it's always the same diagram/symbol you want to use it might be best to save it in a box once and then always use that box. Depens on your usecase, of course.